Custom MusixTex engine for TexShop
I would like to create a custom MusicTex engine for TexShop (v. 5.48) that runs the "three pass system" of MusixTex described in Section 1.3 of the MusixTex Documentation:

etex
musixflx
etex

I understand that in order to do this, I will need to add an MusixTex.engine file to ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/, but I do not know what script to use in this file to make it work.
I want to be able to use MusixTex in LaTeX documents through \usepackage{musixtex}. Currently, when I do this, I get the initial rendering, but I do not get the refinement of the "three pass system" that I need to complete the typesetting.
I would like to accomplish this entirely in TexShop without resorting to the terminal command line.
MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}\nostartrule
\hsize=100mm
\generalmeter{\meterfrac24}%
\parindent 0pt
\generalsignature{-3}
\nostartrule
\startpiece\bigaccid
\NOtes\qu{ce}\en\bar
\NOtes\qu{gh}\en\bar
\NOtes\qu{=b}\en
\Notes\ds\cu g\en\bar
\NOtes\qu{^f=f}\en\bar
\NOtes\qu{=e}\itied0e\qu{_e}\en\bar
\Notes\ttie0\Qqbu ed{_d}c\en\bar
\Notes\ibu0b{-2}\qb0{=b}\en
\notes\nbbu0\qb0{=a}\tqh0N\en
\Notes\Dqbu cf\en\bar
\NOtes\uptext{\it tr}\qu e\uptext{\it tr}\qu d\en\bar
\NOtes\qu c\qp\en\Endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}



presumably steps 1 and 3 need to be pdflatex not etex as you are using a latex document to hold the music.

Here's an engine for using musixtex with pdflatex (as you seem to be doing). If you're using another engine (e.g. lualatex or xelatex) you'll need to change the compiler accordingly.
In TeXShop, open a new file and add the following to it:
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin


pdflatex "$1" --file-line-error --synctex=1
musixflx "$1"
pdflatex "$1" --file-line-error --synctex=1

Save this file as musixpdflatex.engine in ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines. Use the dropdown menu in the file save dialogue box to choose the .engine extension.
Open a Terminal window and then set the executable bit for the engine file:
chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/musixpdflatex.engine

Restart TeXShop and now you will have an engine that can be chosen from the Program menu item or accessed with the magic comment:
% !TEX TS-program = musixpdflatex

If you envision using lualatex, then it would make sense to make a second .engine file musixlualatex.engine which runs lualatex rather than pdflatex on the file but is otherwise the same.

That did the trick! Thank you.

If I wanted to create an engine for use with plain TeX, would I just replace pdflatex with etex in the shell script?

Well these days most people want PDF output not DVI, so it would make more sense to use pdftex rather than etex, and even then, if you wanted DVI you would normally use pdftex -output-format dvi 

Yes, I want PDF output; my mistake. pdftex is what I will use. By the way, I have another related question regarding the creation of an M-Tex engine as well. Should I create another thread for that one? Thank you.

You could but engine files are just shell scripts that TeXShop runs, so there's not a lot of complexity to them. There's also the musixtex script which runs the appropriate tool depending on the file extension given (overridable with options). Perhaps it would make sense to make an engine for that. Another option would be to use the arara engine and make arara rules for the various music related tools.

I did a little reading on the arara option you mentioned, and it seems to be what I am after. The trouble is, I don't have the requisite understanding to set it up. I will post a new question on this issue, and I look forward to your (and others') expert help in my understanding and implementing it.
